# How to redirect query string with dash url using htaccess

Tags: php

How to redirect https://xyz.com/ceoblog/?tag=real-estate-assistant&paged=2  to https://xyz.com/ceoblog/

I have tried all possible solution but its not redirect.

how do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"I have tried all possible solution but its not redirect."` What exactly have you tried? because a simple `301` Redirect would do the trick.

Comment: This question misses required information about what you tried in PHP, or misses required information about what http deamon you are using.

Answer (score 1):

This htaccess rule checks for ANY query string on ceoblog and redirects to ceoblog/

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ceoblog(/?)$ /ceoblog/? [R=301,L]
```

However, looking at the query string this will stop the pagination and tag filter from working correctly - i.e. you will be stuck with just the one page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not working and url is not redirecting.
Please suggest other solution.  
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possible solutions

1. If your looking to store the query string data away, and then just redirect to no query string, you could in your php script do something like:

```
if(count($_GET)) {
    $mydata = $_GET;

    // do stuff with $data, like store it or something

    header("location: /ceoblog");
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

1. If you're looking to just redirect, a simple 301 redirect in an htaccess rule would work perfectly here